# Inno Setup Disable cancel button during installation

Tags: inno-setup

How can I lock the *Cancel* button during the installation?

Answer (score 4):

Set [`AllowCancelDuringInstall` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_allowcancelduringinstall) to `no`.

```
[Setup]
AllowCancelDuringInstall=no
```